# WordPress Plug-In Active installation count

Tags: plugins

I have just submitted my plug-in first time in wordpress successfully, but somehow wordpress is not updating the active installation count on plugin profile page although it has very high downloads everyday.

Below is my wordpress plug-in link :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/accu-auto-backup/

Currently total downloads are 1500+ and active installation are "Fewer Then 10" so how could that possible.

Is there any code need to add into my plug-in readme.txt to enable this ?

below is my readme.txt

```
=== Accu Auto Backup ===
Contributors: dhanashreeinc
Tags: Accu auto backup,auto backup,Database backup,db backup, backup,database, WordPress Database Backup, WP db backup,wp database backup,wp backup,wordpress backup, mysql backup,automatically database backup,website backup,website database backup
Requires at least: 4.0
Tested up to: 4.9.4
Version: 1.0.0
Requires PHP: 5.6
Stable tag: trunk
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
```

thanks in advance for help.

Its been 2 weeks and still they displaying less active installation.

Answer (score 6):

The active install count is updated daily based on update checks from real active installs on active sites. Sites that do not receive any visit on a given day don't count, neither do sites that have just installed the plugin and haven't checked for updates yet.

The download count is always much higher than active install count because it is based on raw data. Each time someone clicks the download button, the count increases. Every update also count as a raw download, including on sites where the plugin is installed but not active.

It would be very easy to artificially increase the download count (just click the button like a mad man), but that won't be of any use because the active install count - which is much more prominently displayed - will not be affected.

Otto is probably the best person to explain how this works, and his multiple comments in this thread provide at lot of additional insights: https://wpchat.com/t/wordpress-org-now-reports-active-plugin-installs/679/26